# Unity5 Building Asset Bundles with scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an asset bundle with scenes. This is what I did in unity4

```
[MenuItem("Bundle/Create ios Scene SceneLoader")]
static void iosBuild(){
    string[] levels = new string []{"Assets/Scenes/01 SceneLoader.unity", "Assets/Scenes/02 Level1.unity","Assets/Scenes/02 Level2.unity" ,"Assets/Scenes/02 Level3.unity"};

    BuildPipeline.BuildStreamedSceneAssetBundle( levels, "Assets/Bundles/bundle-ios.unity3d", BuildTarget.iOS); 
}
```

After that I load my bundle via this code:

```
using(WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (url, 0)){
        while(!www.isDone){
            status.text = "loading \n" + (www.progress * 100).ToString() + "%";
            yield return null;
        }

        yield return www;
        //check if server response is an error
        if (www.error != null){
            throw new Exception("WWW download had an error: " + url + " " + www.error);
        }

        //Load the asset bundle
        AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;

        //obsolete bundle.LoadAll();
        bundle.LoadAllAssets();
        Application.LoadLevel ("01 SceneLoader");
    }
```

This code worked in unity4, but now, when I load my Scene, all the script references are missing. Objects are in the scene but no scripts. Also, unity tells me that BuildStreamedSceneAssetBundle is obsolete. So my question is, why aren't my script references in the core scene ? So that when I load an asset bundle, all the scripts aren't missing. Also my NGUI Atlas that I use in the loaded scene is missing.

Would be glad if someone has an idea!

EDIT: the first string in "levels" will have all script references. How is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem is unity bug.
My project has same problem.

I found solution, but it's very inconvenient.
If you must use scene asset bundle, 
make one asset bundle per one scene.

```
string[] level1 = new string []{"Assets/Scenes/01 SceneLoader.unity"};
string[] level2 = new string []{"Assets/Scenes/02 Level1.unity"};
.....

BuildPipeline.BuildStreamedSceneAssetBundle( level1, "Assets/Bundles/bundle-ios1.unity3d", BuildTarget.iOS); 
BuildPipeline.BuildStreamedSceneAssetBundle( level2, "Assets/Bundles/bundle-ios2.unity3d", BuildTarget.iOS); 
.....
```

I used "BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles" func at Unity5.
But I think that "BuildPipeline.BuildStreamedSceneAssetBundle" and  "BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles" is similar.